# How to calculate percentage in group by with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, average

I have a table with this schema:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|   id    |   provider  |  status   | message |
+---------------------------------------------+
|    1    |   Google    |  success  |  ...    |
|    2    |   Facebook  |  failure  |  ...    |
|    3    |   Facebook  |  failure  |  ...    |
|    4    |   Google    |  failure  |  ...    |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I need to know percentage of `failure` for example:

> google -> 50% failure
>
> Facebook -> 100% failure

I use mysql 5.7

I tried to reach this destination using group by, but I couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. I like to do this with `avg()`:

```
select provider, avg(status = 'failure') failure_ratio
from mytable
group by provider
```

For each `provider`, this gives you a numeric value between `0` and `1` that represents the ratio of records in `'failure'` `status`. You can multiply that by `100` if you want a percentage instead.